# Spring Boot - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I got exception `PageNotFound: Request method 'POST' not supported` in my Spring Boot app.

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

UserWrapper userWrapper = new UserWrapper();

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Content-type: application/*")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getCredentials(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {

    User user = userWrapper.wrapUser(userDTO);
    if (userDTO.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }
}
```

I am sending post request at `localhost:8080/api/login` but it doesn't work. Have you got any idea?

**EDIT:**

UserDTO:

```
public class UserDTO implements Serializable {

private String email;
private String password;
//getters and setters
```

And json i send:

```
{
   "email":"email@email.com",
   "password":"password"
}
```

Comment: what is your content type that you are sending up? what do you specify in the header?

Comment: I'm sending json, in header I have `Content-type: application/json`

Comment: can you show `UserDTO` class and the `JSON` you're posting? Example data is fine., just for structure.

Comment: I added it into post

Comment: which web container are you using? how are you deploying your application?

Comment: Try catching your info with @RequestParam, then you can be sure its not spring boot issue

Answer (score 14):

I solved this issue by disabling the CSRF.

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thx. Fixed an org.restlet behing spring boot 2 problem.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem. I removed headers from RequestMapping and added `@Autowired` annotation for `UserWrapper` and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that occurs if you are using JPA. The spring boot Repository has all the request built in. so your request have to **Match** the Repository requests This is the only example I found that has a working Spring Boot POST
https://dzone.com/articles/crud-using-spring-data-rest
The key is you have to **Match** the Repository Rest call

your repository Iterface will look like this plus any override there is no impl class

```
public interface UseerRepository extends  CrudRepository<User, Integer>{
}
```

your controller will look like this.  Notice the request value **/users** It is the entity name with an S on the end

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping("/api/login")//this will return the login page
public String home() {
    return "login";
}
UserWrapper userWrapper = new UserWrapper();
//this will do the post
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST,    headers = "Content-type: application/*")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getCredentials(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {

User user = userWrapper.wrapUser(userDTO);
if (userDTO.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
} else {
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
  }
}
```

Your Application config file should look like this  Notice @ComponentScan no basepackage={"com"} If you do that then your JPA does not work

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);         
}
}
```

If you want to overwrite a repository POST request do it in the controller or a service class  I hope I explained it well enough but that example does work and you do not have to write a lot of crude code anymore